A Priori Sample Size Needed for Linear Mixed Model
I'm new to the site so I apologize if I fail to follow some norms.
I am an early-stage doc student and am still early in my stats courses. In a class, I want to propose the following experiment based on cross-sectional studies which have hinted at this interaction:
IV: Personality Traits (in this experiment, there will be 9, likely measured as a number 0-1, and will remain the same for the subject for the entirety of the 4 tests below)
Moderator: 2x2 of Hi/Low Time and Hi/Low Uncertainty (this is the manipulation, and each participant will be measured at each of the 4 quadrants, such that each participant completes 4 puzzles)
DV: Level of a cognitive logic used in a problem-solving question-and-answer puzzle (measured as something like 0-1)
I recently learned that repeated measures ANOVA is on its way out and LMM is replacing it. Regardless I need to determine the sample size needed before I can propose the experiment. I have some minor experience using pwr.f2.test in R, various GPower tests, and I also have some basic regression experience in Stata. My trouble is that I don't know the best way to determine the sample size needed. I am not far along enough in my education to understand previous articles and posts about this topic. Furthermore, some professors have said pwr.f2.test will work while others have suggested simulations is the only way. In either case, I'm not sure how to set this test up for sample size because of my limited knowledge in the area.
I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.
**EDIT: I don't need to know configurations of traits because that's just over my head at this point. I'll probably just need to do 9 different analyses, 1 trait * 4 levels of moderator.

This is a wonderful opportunity to get through the statistical hurdles by learning how to perform that simulation and doing it.  Its payoff is far greater than helping you determine sample size: you will have the opportunity to analyze realistic data before you commit years of study and tuition to performing your research.  You will know how you will need to analyze the data once they are available; you will know how much data you need; and you will have made the inevitable mistakes with inexpensive data rather than your own valuable ones.

So a simulation is the way to go? That's helpful - at the time of posting I was being pointed in three different directions: R packages, GPower, and Simulations. I'll give simulations a shot.

The simr package in R has worked well for me in simulating power for multilevel models.
